# Getting conditioning values from a distribution

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, statistics, distribution

I am trying to capture values from a kernel distribution which gives almost 0 and at the end of the tail. My try is to take values from the `kernel` function , distributed in a timeline from -120 to 120 and make the percentage change for the values from the kernel , so then i can declared an arbitrary rule that 10 consecutive negative changes and have which kernel value is almost 0 i can declare as the starting point from the ending of the curve.

Illustration example for which point of the kernel function i want to obtain.

[image]

in this case the final value which i will like to obtain is around 300

my dataframe looks like (this is not the same example values from above) :

```
df

id   event_time
 1            2
 1            3
 1            3
 1            5
 1            9
 1           10
 2            1
 2            1
 2            2
 2            2
 2            5
 2            5

 # my try

 def find_value(df):

    if df.shape[0] == 1:
        return df.iloc[0].event_time

    kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(df['event_time'])
    time = list(range(-120,120))
    a = kernel(time)
    b = np.diff(a) / a[:-1] * 100
```

so far i have a which represent Y axis from the graph and b which represent the change in Y. The reason that i did this is for making the logic made at the begging but dont know how to code it. after writing the function i was thinking in using an `groupby` and a `apply`

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is tbh. You want to compute the difference of all values with respect to the last value? What is `b` supposed to mean?

Comment: b is percentage change between the values of a , is the slope of the curve

Comment: Your question still doesn’t make sense to me, sorry. You have a given Kernel function and want to get The last non-zero value of it? Normally a kernel is a window function that you pass another function for a convolution. What is the other function?